# Api call empty table

Tags: angular, typescript, api, datasource

I'm trying to fill a table with data that I get from an API call, I managed to see the data in my console but in my view file I can't see anything.

Account.ts :

```
  resp;
  ELEMENT_DATA: Account[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email','phone','address','city'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Account>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  getAccountData(){
    this.resp = this.accountService.getAccount().subscribe(
      data => this.dataSource.data = data as Account[]
    )
  }
  constructor(private accountService:AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccountData();
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
}
```

The format that I get the data is this :

```
{status: 200, text: "OK", body: Array(5388) .. }
```

And I need only the array that is inside the body.

Someone maybe knows what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like some ChangeDetection issue wit mat-table; Does something like this work?

```data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Account>(data as Account[]);```

Creating new instance should trigger the ChangeDetection in the component.

Comment: @LukaszGawrys Did you mean like this? 
`getAccountData(){
    this.resp = this.accountService.getAccount().subscribe(
      data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Account>(data as Account[])
    )
  }`
if so then it didn't change anything...

Comment: @LukaszGawrys I added what I want from the raw data, can you review my question again please?

Comment: Ok so please try the solution from my first comment but pass data.body to the constructor instead of just data.

Comment: @LukaszGawrys Thank you very much ! that worked for me. Now I'm trying to implement a paginator but apparntly the data from the API is loading after the paginator and the paginator doesn't work.. do you have any idea to solve it?